# User-interface and Menu in Haskell

Tags: user-interface, haskell, functional-programming

I am creating social network in haskell based on graphs. The problem is that I want to create a user interface for people to interact. This user interface should consists of text that shows what the options are and based on key inputs, users can search the database and perform actions on the data set.

What I have already done:

-Explored this thread "[Simple text menu in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799588/simple-text-menu-in-haskell)"

-Installed packages such as haskelline

Problem is that I have just started learning Haskell and the progress has been damn slow compared to my experience with other languages, so I havent benefitted from the above resources to an extent that has solved my problem.

Would someone be kind enough to share a template consisting of a CL interface menu screen. That asks users to press keys mapped for different functions. Then after output, goes back to the main menu.

Here is an example of what my functions look like.

```
isFriend :: Node -> Node -> [Edge] -> Bool
isFriend _ _ [] = False
isFriend a b (x:xs)
 | edgeCompare a b x == True = True
 | otherwise = isFriend a b xs
```

So the menu could say "press I" to search for friends, that would prompt the user to enter a name. This would run my function with the argument inputted by the user.

Thank you :)

Comment: This exact thing was provided in the thread you reference. Your question is thus pretty vague... Do you want more in depth explanations ?

Comment: Slow progress is more or less to be expected. When one is used to one programming language paradigm, and moves to a different one, a significant effort is required. I'd guess that moving from imperative&procedural to imperative&OOP is easier than, say, imperative&OOP to functional, especially to pure functional like Haskell. Yet, precisely because it's so different, it's worth learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553473/660339), I've created this:

```
import System.IO (stdin, hSetEcho, hSetBuffering, BufferMode(NoBuffering), hReady)
import Control.Monad (when)

getKey = reverse <$> getKey' ""
  where getKey' chars = do
          char <- getChar
          more <- hReady stdin
          (if more then getKey' else return) (char:chars)

-- Simple menu controller
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  hSetEcho stdin False
  key <- getKey
  when (key /= "\ESC") $ do
    case key of
      "w"     -> putStrLn "↑"
      "s"     -> putStrLn "↓"
      "d"     -> putStrLn "→"
      "a"     -> putStrLn "←"
      "\n"    -> putStrLn "⎆"
      "\DEL"  -> putStrLn "⎋"
      _       -> return ()
    main
```

[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553473/660339)] also shows how to detect arrow key presses, which is cool! Changing the line buffering of stdin is important.

You'll probably want your application loop to have some initial application state, and pass it around as an argument.

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot